# How to use ES6 reduce to sum values across another property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, reduce

I have an array in this form:

```
const products = 
[{product: "a", volume: 3}, {product: "b", volume: 7}, {product: "c", volume: 5}],

[{product: "a", volume: 8}, {product: "b", volume: 10}, {product: "c", volume: 4}]
```

and I need to sum them and make sure the volumes for each product are not more than in another object with the same structure:

```
const ProductLimits: ProductVolumes[] = [{product: "a", volume: 10}, {product: "b", volume: 22}, {product: "c", volume: 12}]
```

Have used

```
products.flatMap(x => x.map(y => {
return { product: y.product, volume: y.volume }}));
```

which flattens the first array of arrays to a single array:

```
[{product: "a", volume: 3}, {product: "b", volume: 7}, {product: "c", volume: 5},
{product: "a", volume: 8}, {product: "b", volume: 10}, {product: "c", volume: 4}]
```

Then, in order to do the summing, I'm doing

```
.reduce(acc: IInterface, i) => {
   acc[i.product] = acc[i.product] || 0) + i.volume;
   return acc;
});
```

using

```
interface IInterface {
product: string;
volume: number;
[product: string]: any;
}
```

since Typescript demands an index signature.

However the problem is the reduce is returning a correct list of products except for the first one, where after 3 iterations it has:

```
product: "a"
volume: 3
b: 7
c: 5
```

The issue is clearly with the structure of the first value of acc.

Any ideas on how to fix that first iteration or of a better approach?

Comment: Your first array is not valid

Comment: why not just flat() for the first part

Comment: Your `reduce` is also not valid, the `reduce` function takes a callback and an initial value. Either you formatted wrong when copying or it actually shouldn't work.

Comment: @RonnyEfronny Can assure it does compile and run and gives the result I described.  Something's not right of course so trying to work out why it doesn't work properly

Comment: @user3775501 you need to add an accumulator to the reduce, perhaps an empty {}

Comment: also idk if its a typo but `acc[i.product] = (acc[i.product] || 0) + i.volume` u missed the opening (

Comment: @cmgchess how do you add that in? The accumulator is the IInterface acc, how would you add the initial value to it without having it as product and volume automatically?

Comment: @cmgchess the opening ( is after the =

Comment: at the end of reduce `return acc;
},{})`

Comment: @user3775501 something like [this](https://shorturl.at/sJK04) ?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [`flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to flatten the array. Then you need to seed/ initialized [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to an empty object `{}`, then the aggregation should work (you need to fix that missing bracket!). Last but not least you just need to map the aggregated values into the desired target structure using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

Note I am also ussing a [nullish coalescing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment) as I think this is more readable then working with falsy values.

```js
const input = [
  [{
    product: "a",
    volume: 3
  }, {
    product: "b",
    volume: 7
  }, {
    product: "c",
    volume: 5
  }],
  [{
    product: "a",
    volume: 8
  }, {
    product: "b",
    volume: 10
  }, {
    product: "c",
    volume: 4
  }]
];
const aggregated = input.flat()
  .reduce((acc, i) => {
    acc[i.product] = (acc[i.product] ??= 0) + i.volume;
    return acc;
  }, {});

const output = Object.entries(aggregated).map(([product, volume]) => ({ product, volume }));

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let products = [[{product: "a", volume: 3}, {product: "b", volume: 7}, {product: "c", volume: 5}], [{product: "a", volume: 8}, {product: "b", volume: 10}, {product: "c", volume: 4}]]


let SingleArray =  products.flat()
function Customfun(){
    let map = new Map();
    let type = "";
    for(let obj of SingleArray){
        if(map.has(obj.product)){
           let vol = map.get(obj.product)
           map.set(obj.product,obj.volume+vol);
        }
        else{
            map.set(obj.product,obj.volume);
        }
    }

    let ProductsList = [];
    for(let [key,val] of map.entries()){
        ProductsList = [...ProductsList,{product:key, volume:val}]
    }
    
    return ProductsList;
}
console.log(Customfun())
```